# MySQL GROUP BY extended

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `t` (
        `customer` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `item` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `debit` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `credit` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        INDEX `customer` (`customer`),
        INDEX `item` (`item`));
INSERT INTO `t` (`customer`, `item`, `debit`, `credit`) VALUES ('cust1', 'item1', 10.00, NULL);
INSERT INTO `t` (`customer`, `item`, `debit`, `credit`) VALUES ('cust2', 'item2', NULL, 10.00);
INSERT INTO `t` (`customer`, `item`, `debit`, `credit`) VALUES ('cust3', 'item2', 20.00, NULL);
INSERT INTO `t` (`customer`, `item`, `debit`, `credit`) VALUES ('cust4', 'item3', NULL, 50.00);
INSERT INTO `t` (`customer`, `item`, `debit`, `credit`) VALUES ('cust5', 'item1', 30.00, NULL);
INSERT INTO `t` (`customer`, `item`, `debit`, `credit`) VALUES ('cust6', 'item3', NULL, 40.00);
```

i need to count number of customers per item and sum the debit and credit column for each item so it will look something like this

[image: screenshot]

using the query:

```
SELECT item, count(*) as num_of_custs, SUM(debit) AS debit, SUM(credit) AS credit
FROM t
GROUP BY item
```

but i need to separate 20 and 10 (in second row) into two separate rows. in other words, each row must have either debit or credit value but not both.

i appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data does not have debits and credits on the same row, so you can do this with a single `group by`:

```
SELECT item, count(*) as num_of_custs, SUM(debit) AS debit, SUM(credit) AS credit
FROM t
GROUP BY item, (case when debit is null then 1 else 0 end);
```